# How to remove marker when click button

Tags: leaflet, markers, preact

I am creating a Leaflet Map Widget using Preact and webpack.
I have 3 buttons with a single map. Below images shows what I implemented.

[image]

when click one single button, the map will show some locations. Like wise other buttons also have each locations. First I clicked "Cemeteries" button, Its fine. locations are displaying on the map. But after that I click "Funeral Homes" button, still have the "cemeteries" locations also. When I click "crematoria" button, same problem, "cemeteries", "Funeral Homes" and "crematoria" locations are displaying together.

What I want is, when I click a one single button, map will show only the each button's locations and when I click another button, previous clicked button locations need to remove.

In my ***componentDidMount()*** I created the map.

```
this.state.map = createMap('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        let urlll = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?';
        this.state.map.addLayer(tileLayer(
            urlll, 
            {attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'MY_MAPBOX_ID',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'
        })
        )
```

After that I create 3 methods for button click events. This is a one method

```
handleMapCemeteries (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var locationsdemo = [
            ["LOCATION_1", 11.8166, 13.0942],
            ["LOCATION_2", 87.9804, 76.9189],
            ["LOCATION_3", 10.7202, 45.5621],
            ["LOCATION_4", 11.3889, 11.6277],
            ["LOCATION_5", 10.5929, 43.6325]
          ];

        let marketIcon = icon({
            iconUrl: markerIcon,
            iconRetinaUrl: markerIcon,
            iconAnchor: [5, 25],
            popupAnchor: [10, -44],
            iconSize: [25, 35],
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < locationsdemo.length; i++) {
            markeDemo =  marker([locationsdemo[i][1], locationsdemo[i][2]], {
                icon: marketIcon,
                draggable: true,
                title: 'Hover Text',     
            }).bindPopup(locationsdemo[i][0]).addTo(this.state.map);

        }
}
```

Is anyone know how to remove markers when button click?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the markers to the map (`.addTo(this.state.map);`) add them to a LayerGroup / FeatureGroup (make sure the group is a global variable and only initialized once):

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.state.map);

...

marker. ... .addTo(fg);
```

and then you can remove all markers:

```
fg.clearLayers();
```